# Setup Athena JDBC connector in Glue 4.0

Tags: jdbc, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I have a data source in Glue, which is configured with partition projection. I can query the data in Athena, however when I load this data source in a Glue 4.0 job, the Spark dataframe returns empty. It seems that partition projection is an Athena-only feature.

To workaround the issue, I would like to setup a JDBC connector for Athena in my Glue job, so I can access the data via Athena, instead of directly querying the Glue catalog. AWS provides instructions and a jar file here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/connect-with-jdbc.html.

So I'm adding the latest jar file (at the time of writing, AthenaJDBC42-2.0.35.1000.jar) into Spark using the `--extra-jars` argument, but I'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.JndiLookup"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
```

Does anyone know how I can address this error?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, I found using an older driver (AthenaJDBC42_2.0.27.1000.jar) worked.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I ended up using boto3 to submit queries to Athena and emulate the behavior I wanted.